# Quadratic and cubic regression in Excel

Tags: excel, regression

I have the following information:

```
  Height    Weight

    170     65
    167     55
    189     85
    175     70
    166     55
    174     55
    169     69
    170     58
    184     84
    161     56
    170     75
    182     68
    167     51
    187     85
    178     62
    173     60
    172     68
    178     55
    175     65
    176     70
```

I want to construct quadratic and cubic regression analysis in Excel. I know how to do it by linear regression in Excel, but what about quadratic and cubic? I have searched a lot of resources, but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: my 1st google result for "excel polynomial regression" is http://people.stfx.ca/bliengme/ExcelTips/Polynomial.htm - what's wrong with that?!?

Comment: @deathApril I suggest you add this as the answer

Comment: @deathApril i've been googling for a how to perform polynomial regressions in Excel. i already found the link you mention; but i don't think it includes anything to do with quadratic or 4th order regressions. i could be wrong: it's horribly written.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You need to use an undocumented trick with Excel's `LINEST` function:

```
=LINEST(known_y's, [known_x's], [const], [stats])
```

### Background

A regular *linear* regression is calculated (with your data) as:

```
=LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21)
```

which returns a single value, the linear slope (`m`) according to the formula:

[image]

which for your data:

[image]

is:

[image]

### Undocumented trick Number 1

You can also use Excel to calculate a regression with a formula that uses an exponent for `x` different from `1`, e.g. x<sup>1.2</sup>:

[image]

using the formula:

```
=LINEST(B2:B21, A2:A21^1.2)
```

which for you data:

[image]

is:

[image]

### You're not limited to one exponent

Excel's `LINEST` function can also calculate multiple regressions, with different exponents on `x` at the same time, e.g.:

```
=LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^{1,2})
```

> **Note:** if locale is set to European (decimal symbol ","), then comma should be replaced by semicolon and backslash, i.e. `=LINEST(B2:B21;A2:A21^{1\2})`

Now Excel will calculate regressions using both x<sup>1</sup> and x<sup>2</sup> at the same time:

[image]

### How to actually do it

The impossibly tricky part there's no obvious way to *see* the other regression values. In order to do that you need to:

- select the cell that contains your formula:

  [image]
- extend the selection the left 2 spaces (you need the select to be at least 3 cells wide):

  [image]
- press <kbd>F2</kbd>
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

  [image]

You will now see your 3 regression constants:

```
  y = -0.01777539x^2 + 6.864151123x + -591.3531443
```

### Bonus Chatter

I had a function that I wanted to perform a regression using *some* exponent:

> y = m×x<sup>k</sup> + b

But I didn't **know** the exponent. So I changed the `LINEST` function to use a cell reference instead:

```
=LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^F3, true, true)
```

With Excel then outputting full stats (the 4th paramter to `LINEST`):

[image]

I tell the **Solver** to maximize R<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

And it can figure out the best exponent. Which for you data:

[image]

is:

[image]

Comment: @Jesse Strictly speaking: you can! You can create a bounty *"in order to award more reputation"*

Comment: Thanks! Note: if you are using Excel for Mac, you do the array formula with CONTROL+U and then ⌘+Z+RETURN

Comment: @Jesse Alright, I upvoted for you.  Edit: Hmm, I get #VALUE! when I insert this formula into my Excel 2010...  Nevermind, I have to use ; instead of , for element separator.  (Hope this helps someone.)

Comment: If you dont want the whole LINEST output or you want to transpose the array output to vertical you can access single results from the array output using INDEX. In your example the R² data could be generated in a single cell with =INDEX(LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^F3, true, true),3,1)

Comment: @Alex: If your computer is set up to a European to locale, i.e.. to use decimal comma (not decimal points), then "{1,2}" must be changed to "{1\2}". (And in addition, commas must be changed to semicolons of course.)

Comment: Very well explained.  But you might note from your final model (y=1.3*10^-36*x^16+b) that over-reliance on technology/mathematics for fitting, without understanding the underlying physics, can lead to meaningless "answers".  I.e. garbage in, garbage out!  And the final model illustrates that beautifully.

Comment: This is not completely undocumented. What's actually happening is that you are creating multiple x vectors in the linest function by using the formula known_x's^{array of powers}, and then regressing against them. And an important note: **if your x values are in rows, then you have to use semicolons instead of commas to separate the list of powers** (this makes your array of powers into a column instead of a row).

Comment: thnx for the great answer ..but I am struggling how this algorithm works. That is what is the difference b/w  `=LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^{1,2})` & `=LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^{2,1})`

Comment: Great answer, thank you, however I am wondering, con we apply this for a multivariate case?  I mean is it possible to use excel to find a multivariate polynomial regression ?

Comment: I could realize in French with that formula: `=LINEST(B2:B21;A2:A21^{1.2})` with a point between each exponent degrees.

Comment: THANK YOU, I didn't know about the escape for european format

Answer (score 14):

I know that this question is a little old, but I thought that I would provide an alternative which, in my opinion, might be a little easier.  If you're willing to add "temporary" columns to a data set, you can use Excel's Analysis ToolPak→Data Analysis→Regression.  The secret to doing a quadratic or a cubic regression analysis is defining the **Input X Range:**.

If you're doing a simple linear regression, all you need are 2 columns, X & Y.  If you're doing a quadratic, you'll need X_1, X_2, & Y where X_1 is the **x** variable and X_2 is **x^2**; likewise, if you're doing a cubic, you'll need X_1, X_2, X_3, & Y where X_1 is the **x** variable, X_2 is **x^2** and X_3 is **x^3**.  Notice how the **Input X Range** is from A1 to B22, spanning 2 columns.

[image: Input for Quadratic Regression Analysis in Excel]

The following image the output of the regression analysis.  I've highlighted the common outputs, including the R-Squared values and all the coefficients.

[image: Coefficients of Quadratic Regression Analysis in Excel]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know this is a bit old, but I have a question here. When doing regression with excel, the inputs should not be independent ? if yes, how can we choose the two columns to be  X and X^2  ?

Answer (score 5):

The LINEST function described in a previous answer is the way to go, but an easier way to show the 3 coefficients of the output is to additionally use the INDEX function.  In one cell, type: =INDEX(LINEST(B2:B21,A2:A21^{1,2},TRUE,FALSE),1) (by the way, the B2:B21 and A2:A21 I used are just the same values the first poster who answered this used... of course you'd change these ranges appropriately to match your data). This gives the X^2 coefficient.  In an adjacent cell, type the same formula again but change the final 1 to a 2... this gives the X^1 coefficient.  Lastly, in the next cell over, again type the same formula but change the last number to a 3... this gives the constant.  I did notice that the three coefficients are very close but not quite identical to those derived by using the graphical trendline feature under the charts tab.  Also, I discovered that LINEST only seems to work if the X and Y data are in columns (not rows), with no empty cells within the range, so be aware of that if you get a #VALUE error.

Comment: If you your computer is set up to use decimal comma instead of decimal points (i.e., European locales; e.g. "3,14" instead of "3.14") then "{1,2}" must be changed to "{1\2}". Yes, a backslash! And as usual commas must be changed to semicolons. So the formula becomes =INDEX(LINEST(B2:B21;A2:A21^{1\2};TRUE;FALSE);1)

Comment: @Spanky You can use LINEST in rows too. Just add TRANSPOSE. Like: =LINEST(TRANSPOSE(D9:M9);TRANSPOSE(D6:M6)^{1\2})