# getting coefficients of logarithmic trendline, EXCEL

Tags: excel, trendline

I was wondering, whether it's possible to get coefficients of logarithmic trendline from an excel chart ? I know you can display them, but I'd like to have them in two different cells.
Thanks in advance for help !

best regards,
Bartek

Comment: Read the display and type them in....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quadratic and cubic regression in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel). This is a slight variant on how to use `LINEST` beyond linear regression

Answer (score 1):

First result for Google search "logarithmic trendline formula excel" works for me:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/

Note that you can right-click the trendline equation and choose Format Trendline Label... with Scientific Format and 14 decimal places to see full precision.