# how to obtain estimation from regression in excel?

Tags: excel

I use datas in excel to produce a graphic.

Then I make a regression, and have an equation. I'd like to know what value would be obtained from the regression (for example, x = 7,6 is the value for which I wanna know an estimation of y).

It is an approximation with a 6 degree polynome.

One wimple method would be this : I have the equation, so I could use it

However, I wondered if there is a fast method to do it? Like I enter 7,6 somewhere to have the result quickly?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at a linear regression line (straight line) you could try the forecast formula

```
=forecast(X, Known Ys, Known Xs)
```

you could also build your own equation automatically from

```
=linest(...)
```

I found the following [on a site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) describing the capabilities of the linest function in excel:

> In addition to using LOGEST to calculate statistics for other
>   regression types, you can use LINEST to calculate a range of other
>   regression types by entering functions of the x and y variables as the
>   x and y series for LINEST. For example, the following formula:
>
> =LINEST(yvalues, xvalues^COLUMN($A:$C))
>
> works when you have a single column of y-values and a single column of
>   x-values to calculate the cubic (polynomial of order 3) approximation
>   of the form:
>
> y = m1*x + m2*x^2 + m3*x^3 + b
>
> You can adjust this formula to calculate other types of regression,
>   but in some cases it requires the adjustment of the output values and
>   other statistics.

or look at:

```
=trend
```

Comment: ahh well that changes everything! I cant remember the math behind coming up with regression so I can't set up a formula for a polynomial for you. sorry.

Comment: take a look at this stackoverflow article on cubic and quadratic regression, you may be able to extrapolate it to the 6th degree polynomial:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel)