# Quadratic and cubic regression in Excel using LINEST

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use `LINEST` in Excel 2013 to get the coefficients for a cubic function but LINEST does not work well with non-linear functions according to this link [MS KB828533](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828533). Apparently this is because of the way collinearity is handled. A similar question is asked here [Quadratic and cubic regression in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel) but it does not address the problem.

Excel's builtin `Column Chart | Trendline (3rd degree poly)` produces correct coefficients. However, `LINEST` as well as `Data Analysis | Regression` both give wrong coefficients.

EDIT: Excel's builtin `Column Chart` does **NOT** produce correct coefficients for polynomials. Only use `Column Chart` trendline for linear data! (please see answer).

This is my data:

```
x     y 
2006 7798 
2007 8027 
2008 9526 
2009 11661 
2010 16014 
2011 18731 
2012 23405 
2013 25294 
2014 28578
```

I can only get the third coefficent (here `x3`) using this:

```
={LINEST(y;(x-AVERAGE(x))^{1,2,3})}
```

Results:

```
Coef    Chart       LINEST
x3      -62.295     -62.295
x2      1098.254    163.834
x1      -2746.214   3564.226
intcpt  9528.659    15467.104
        CORRECT     x3 correct, rest WRONG
```

I have also tried a more complex `LINEST` like this:

```
={MMULT(LINEST(y;(x-AVERAGE(x))^{1,2,3});
IFERROR(COMBIN({3;2;1;0};{3,2,1,0})*(-AVERAGE(x))^({3;2;1;0}-{3,2,1,0});0))}
```

But in similar fashion only `x3` is correct and the rest is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Excel LINEST for non-linear function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out that using `anything else but XY Scatter Plot` to calculate regression coefficients for polynomials (or a trendline), **will produce wrong coefficients**.

Conclusively, do **not use** **Line**, **Bar** and **Column** charts to calculate regression coefficients for polynomials. The following image shows the difference in calculated coefficients - the top figure uses `XY Scatter Plot` and produces correct coefficients while bottom figure is created with a `Column` chart. Both figures uses the same data.

[image: XY plot vs Column plot trendline coefficients for polynomials]